# pythons os.walk() returns different base on gh-actions workflow run than that on local machine

Tags: python, github-actions

I'm trying to write names of dirs and name of files that each dir contain into a file using `os.walk()`, the fn works fine on my local system but `os.walk()` doesn't return sequential bases on ***gh-actions*** workflow run.

```py
def refactor_sidebar():
    collapsed = False
    open(SIDEBAR, "w").close()
    with open(SIDEBAR, "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("export default Sidebar = [\n")
        for base, _, files in os.walk(SOLUTION_FOLDER): // 
            if base == "./docs/solution":
                continue
            problem_index = base.removeprefix("./docs/solution/")
            print(base)
            file.write(
                "   {\n"
                f'      text: "{problem_index}",\n'
                "       collapsible: true,\n"
                f"      collapsed: {str(collapsed).lower()},\n"
                "       items: [\n"
            )
            for md in files:
                file.write(
                    "           {\n"
                    f'              text: "{md[:-3]}",\n'
                    f'              link: "/solution/{problem_index}/{md}",\n'
                    "           },\n"
                )
            file.write("        ],\n" " },\n")
            if not collapsed:
                collapsed = True
        file.write("]")
```

base returned on my local system ✅

```
./docs/solution/0001-0100
./docs/solution/0101-0200
./docs/solution/0201-0300
./docs/solution/0301-0400
./docs/solution/0401-0500
./docs/solution/0501-0600
./docs/solution/0601-0700
./docs/solution/0701-0800
./docs/solution/0801-0900
./docs/solution/1001-1100
./docs/solution/1101-1200
./docs/solution/1201-1300
./docs/solution/1401-1500
./docs/solution/1501-1600
./docs/solution/2201-2300
```

base returned on ***gh-actions*** workflow run ❌

```
./docs/solution
./docs/solution/0501-0600
./docs/solution/1101-1200
./docs/solution/1501-1600
./docs/solution/0101-0200
./docs/solution/2201-2300
./docs/solution/0301-0400
./docs/solution/1001-1100
./docs/solution/0601-0700
./docs/solution/0401-0500
./docs/solution/0801-0900
./docs/solution/0001-0100
./docs/solution/0701-0800
./docs/solution/1201-1300
./docs/solution/1401-1500
./docs/solution/0201-0300
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `sorted()` function to sort the directories.

```py
>>> for base, _, files in sorted(os.walk(SOLUTION_FOLDER)):
        ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).